# How to stop iterator after N iterations in rust?

Tags: rust, iterator

Is there a rust idiom to stop an iterator after a given amount of iteration?

```rust
let mut i = 0;

for (available_id, _) in
    self.table
        .iter()
        .enumerate()
        .filter(|(id, &mut f)| (f & ENTITY_USED_BIT) == 0)
{
    // do something...

    i += 1;
    if i >= N {
        break;
    }
}
```

This *works* but I can't find an iterator method like `.enumerate()` or `.stop_after(N)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm very new to Rust but it looks like [take](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Exactly this! Important note: `.take(N)` guarantee iterator will stop after `N` iteration. But it does not guarantee those `N` iteration would be reached (`filter().take(3)` could iterate less than 3 times. If you must iterate *exactly* `N` times, you need to keep track of iteration count.